# spawning a child process and getting result in python infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I have two Python functions (dummy examples)

```
def append_element(input_list, elem):
    input_list.append(elem)
    return input_list


def process_list(input_list):
    # do some time expensive work on input_list
    return input_list
```

that are called as part of an infinite loop

```
input_list = []
i = 0
while True:
    input_list = append_element(input_list, i)
    if len(input_list) == 50:
        res = process_list(input_list)
        print(res)
        input_list = []
    i += 1
    # some exit condition from infinite loop
```

Since the function process_list takes a long time, I would like to refactor my code so that process_list is part of a child process and the infinite loop "prepares" the next input_list in the meantime, while waiting for the child process to complete. This would be something along the lines:

```
input_list = []
i = 0
has_child = False
while True:
    input_list = append_element(input_list, i)
    if len(input_list) == 50:
        if has_child:
            # wait for previously created child process to finish
            res = result of child process
            print(res)
            has_child = False

        # create child process in which process_list is called
        has_child = True
        input_list = [] # start preparing another list in the meantime
    # some exit condition from infinite loop
```

I am not sure what part of the multiprocessing module is better suited to achieve this. Please note that I need to be able to access the result of the child process. Any MWE or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems like only imap or imap_unordered is appropriate

Comment: If this `input_list` code is your real code, then doing this is not worth your effort, as all the processing for `input_list` will be extremely fast. In fact, you could find yourself falling prey to "premature optimization". You'd be better off optimizing `process_list` and getting it to run faster.

Comment: There's a logic error in your loop: when it collects the second batch of 50 inputs and has_child is true, it displays the result for the first batch then throws the second batch away. Instead you should wait for results conditionally but start a batch unconditionally.

Comment: How long does append_element take? Is it very fast or could it take significant time?

Comment: @deltab thank you for the comment, I edited the code accordingly. append_element is very fast (relative to my needs): it runs in 0.01s. In contrast, process_list runs in 0.1s (10 times slower) and it's important for my application to keep the time per loop under 0.03s